# Set multiple <span>'s texts with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this markup in asp.net mvc4 app.

```
<div style="margin-top: 35px; margin-right: 10px; padding-left:2px; border: solid 1px #DCE8E8; height:230px;">
                        We are located at 
                        <span id="txtPhysicalAdd"/><br />
                        <div><span id="txtPostalAdd"/><br /></div>
                        <div>Phone#<br /></div>
                        <div><span id="txtMobile1_2"/><span id="txtMobile2"/><br /></div>
                        <span id="txtTown"/><br />
                        <span id="txtTelephone1"/><br />
                        <label id="txtCountry"/><br />
                        <a href="@Url.Content("~/site/Contact/ContactUs")"><span id="txtEmail"/></a>
                        <br />
                    </div>
```

In the left Nav panel I want to set contact info. It is in the _layout.cshtml hence the use of this JQuery snippet.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
var url = '@Url.Action("GetPrimaryContact","Contact")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            success: function(returndata) {
    if (returndata.ok) {
                        var physicalAdd = returndata.data.PhysicalAddress;
                        var postalAdd = returndata.data.PostalAddress;
                        var mobile1 = returndata.data.Mobile1;
                        var mobile2 = returndata.data.Mobile2;
                        var telephone1 = returndata.data.Telephone1;
                        var town = returndata.data.City;
                        var country = returndata.data.SelectedCountryName;
                        var email = returndata.data.Email;
                        $('#txtPhysicalAdd').text(physicalAdd);
                        $('#txtPostalAdd').text(postalAdd);
                        $('#txtMobile1').text(mobile1);
                        $('#txtMobile1_2').text(mobile1);
                        $('#txtMobile2').text(mobile2);
                        $('#txtTown').text(town);
                        $('#txtTelephone1').text(telephone1);
                        $('#txtCountry').text(country);
                        $('#txtEmail').text(email);
                        //window.alert(' email : ' + mobile2);
                }
                else {
                    window.alert(' error : ' + returndata.message);
                }
            }
        });
```

Problem is on running it it populate only the fisrt value of such the when I Firebug-inspect element I see

```
<div style="margin-top: 35px; margin-right: 10px; padding-left:2px; border: solid 1px #DCE8E8; height:230px;">
We are located at
<span id="txtPhysicalAdd">Kahawa wendani opposite Kahawa Garrison</span>
</div>
```

if I comment any of the field in the JQuery, the first in the remaining is polulated and the rest ignored. Also if I have another field e.g in page header it is mapped but ignored in my div above. Please assist. :)

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct JSON coming out from the ajax call ?

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

> Attribute definitions
>
> id = name [CS] This attribute assigns a name to an element. **This
>   name must be unique in a document.**

There are different ways to solve your problem.  An easy one is to give the controls the same class name, then use a class selector.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TtcAY/

```
$('#btn').click(
  function() 
    {
        $('.mobile').val('212 867 5309');
        $('.country').val('Wottsamattau');
    });
```

Comment: thanks alot. My Id's are unique. But one thing I have realized so far is when I use span or div it behaves as above. But when I used <p id="##"/> it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I used p's for paragraphs in place of span's and divs and it worked fine.